# Can't find stack view button on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am studying Xcode from the official apple website and it explain how to merge ui elements with the button "stack view" , I have the latest version of Xcode, but I can't find this button, how I can create a stack view or similar thing?

From the official doc:

[image]

Comment: Are you using XCode 7 Beta? Because `UIStackView` are new in iOS9, and needs XCode7.

Comment: Then you can't. UIStackView are available since iOS9 (in Beta) and so need XCode7.

Comment: ah ok, there is an alternative on Xcode 6?

Comment: They changed the button for Xcode 10: It's now a simple rectangle with an arrow pointing downwards (they removed the lines for the rows). Clicking on it opens a menu that gives you the option to "Embed in View" - "Stack View". You can also use the Library to add a `Stack View` (horizontal or vertical) and then add your layout elements as children.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first pages of this [Tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson2.html) where it seems that you got the image, there is a screenshot with the XCode Logo with a "Beta" sign.

[`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/) are introduced in iOS9. 
So it can only be used with an XCode that supports iOS9 (currently in Beta): XCode 7 (Beta).

Even if you could use the iOS9 SDK in XCode 6, I think that it wouldn't have the "Stack View" Button. Maybe Apple will give a last update to XCode 6 to supports iOS9, but that is just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Xcode 7. and I ran into the same problem and couldn't find the stack button. After I enable "Use Auto Layout" under "Interface Builder Document" section in the Utility View, stack buttons show up.
"Use Auto Layout" is enabled by default. Please check if it is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Xcode 13.1 and it's been renamed to 'Embed In' with 'Stack View' within it.